# Gradle dependencies for several projects

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I have some projects in directory

```
Dir
  |____ Progect 1
  |____ Progect 2
  |____ Progect 3
```

In project 1 i need use class from project 2. How do I get the required dependencie on the project 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import Project 1 under of it import Project 2 and Project 3 as Module.And Select Project Structure it will show window  in that select dependencies  Choose those two projects as ModuleDependency.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're building a java project, in the build script of project one, just declare a project dependency:

```
//project1/build.gradle
dependencies{
    compile project(":project2")
}
```

Comment: i try do this. And i get error

Error:(26, 0) Project with path ':project2' could not be found in project ':app'.

Comment: have you included the project2 as subproject via settings.gradle?

Comment: nope=( after i add include, i get 
Error:(33, 0) Could not find property ':project2' on DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':app'', configuration='default'}.